# What would be a good mathematical model to measure the degree of homogeneity of a mixture?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, vectors, mathematical-modeling

At my current workplace, we are looking to quantify a batch to say how "similar/dissimilar" the items are. The problem can be stated like so (transformed for public posting):

We have parts that can be assembled from different "buckets". Each *bucket* can have different colored pieces of the same type e.g., colored: triangular or circular pieces, cubes or cylinders etc.,

A particular part is assembled by picking pieces from each bucket. For simplicity we may assume that pieces are picked from *all* buckets. It looks something like this:

[image: Matrix representation]

**Problem:** Compute how *similar* (or dissimilar) the parts in a batch are. The image above is a batch of 5 parts. The individual values would be *categorical variables* like `red, green, blue` in this example.

**Explanation:** *Similarity* is something we can define with regards to color. So if all parts have the same "row of data": $a-p-m-e-i$ for Part1 above, we say the homogeneity is 100% (or heterogeneity is 0%). And if each part is made by picking a unique piece from the buckets we say homogeneity is 0% (or heterogeneity is 100%). Everything else is *somewhere in between* and that is the measure I'm trying to come up with, for a particular batch.

**Current Idea:** Treat this like a vector problem: We have 2 vectors representing the 0-homog and 100-homog points. Given a batch we compute another vector V and see how close it is to the 0-homog and how far from the 100-homog vectors (i.e., imagine point placed on a line segment between two endpoints). We only need a metric for homogeneity in a particular batch. Would this be a mathematically accurate way of computing similarity? Are there alternate ways? Existing references?

**Extension:** The above won't work if we have parts that are only assembled from a *subset* of the buckets in a batch. What modification could be done to allow for this scenario?

**Update:** A simple "count" of each element in a column should provide a number on how many different types of color are used.So $n\cdot a$ implies only `a` is used, but $\frac{n}{3}a+\frac{n}{3}b+\frac{n}{3}c$ would be the "ideal" heterogeneity vector i.e., since it's distributed across three value ranges.

Comment: Is the sum of any row constant?  Can we think of the entries as being percentages (i.e. the percent of part $i$ built from bucket $j$)?  If not, how should the rows a-p-m-e-i and 2a-2p-2m-2e-2i compare in terms of your intuitive idea of homogeneity?

Comment: Is there a concrete goal of homogeneity, i.e. a condition/outcome that we're trying to optimize?

Comment: For the sum: unfortunately no. We can't rely on that. These "values" are mapped to a "count" and not really numeric so to speak. They're more like categorical variables.

Goal: We completely lack this measure but we seem to talk about it a lot and everyone seems to use their intuition to understand what it means and I was hoping to provide a more concrete metric.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - See update. We are not going to be optimizing for anything with the value though. Everyone talks about it and they probably understand what they mean but *no one* in the industry has a metric to ground this more rigorously. I was curious if there is something I could leverage from the MathLand :)

Comment: Regarding your extension, one idea is to include "N/A" as a color, which is to say that the bucket is not used for the part

Comment: I think it would help if we could come up with a measure that works in the one-bucket scenario, and try to generalize

Comment: Does the number of buckets have to match the number of parts?

Comment: The number of buckets is independent to that of the parts. It'll most likely be a "rectangular" matrix...For `N/A` it could work as a catch-all category where it's expected the "ideal" value is $0$ for it. The single bucket case works quite trivially per the update above AFAIK hence the generalization. But posting to see if this is really a *sound* way to measure something like this.

Comment: I guess the problem is that I don't understand how your system works, even in the single bucket case.  Yes, we can count how often each color is used, but how would you like to make that into a homogeneity/heterogeneity percentage?

Comment: "And if each part is made by picking a unique piece from the buckets " isn't clear to me --- I think the word "unique" is ambiguous here. If the second row were `a-p-m-e-k`, and there were only two rows, would that be completely heterogeneous (because the two parts differ in their last index)? Or would it have to differ from the first piece in ALL slots, i.e., the way the current second piece does? If it's the latter, then are there guaranteed to be more "options" in each column than there are pieces? If there are only two options for col 1, and you have 3 pieces, must homogeneity be $<100$%?

Comment: Perhaps you can expand your question with two or three more examples, preferably ones where we know the possible entries for each column, and in which there are only one or two or three columns, but a fair bunch of pieces, and give a kind of "guesstimate" of how "homogeneous" you feel each one is, and why. Right now we're trying to guess a function on a high dimensional space based on one known value, and one example whose value we know is *not* "1", but nothing else. That's not a lot of data...

Comment: @JohnHughes - you are correct about `a-p-m-e-k`. If they only differ in the last index, their homogeneity will be $<100\%$ but would be "closer to 100 than to 0" so to speak.

Comment: So now imagine you've got perfectly heterogeneous items, and you add a new column, with only one "option"...then suddenly they look *less* heterogeneous. This seems...peculiar. I think you need to give us a few more examples, perhaps. Consider, too, this case:
`Item 1  a d g
Item 2  b e h
Item 3  c f k
Item 4  a d g
Item 5  b e h
Item 6  c f k`
That's as heterogeneous as 6 items can be..except that there are strong correlations between the columns. Does that matter? Or is it just as good as if the columns were more shuffled?

Answer (score 1):

One possible definition of homogeneity is to test how unlikely is is that the results would have been generated by sampling from a discrete uniform distribution for each bucket for each part:

Let $b \in B$ be a given bucket, and $C_b$ be the set of colors available for components from that bucket (including $N/A$ per a suggestion in the comments). If we define $X_{ib}$ as the selected color for the part $i$ from bucket $b$, then 
$$P(X_{ib} = c \in C_b)\sim \text{DiscreteUniform(C_b)} \implies P(X_{ib} = c \in C_b) = \frac{1}{|C_b|}$$

For any given part $i$, we have the vector $X_i := (X_{ib})_{b\in B}$ that records the color choices from each bucket.

Our null hypothesis $H_0$ is that the parts are constructed by selecting at random from each bucket for each part according to the Discrete Uniform distribution for that bucket.

If we have $N$ parts, then the distribution of the colors selected for a given bucket $b$ *across all parts* (i.e., the "column" distribution) will be a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

What we want to test is if the observed distribution of colors among parts for all buckets is consistent with the null hypothesis. We can represent "expectation" by noting that the expected number of times a particular color $c$ is chosen from bucket $b$ (i.e., $e_{cb}$) is $\frac{N}{|C_b|}$. This will give us the expected number of times each bucket-color combination should occur among our $N$ parts (e.g., red-cylinder). The observed number of times a given bucket-color combination occurs is $O_{bc}$, where

$$O_{bc} = \sum_{i}^{N} \mathbf{1}_{c}(X_{ib})$$

Similar to a chi-square goodness of fit test, we can quantify the discrepancy of the observations from our expectations using a deviation statistic $d_{bc}$. For example, $d_{bc} = |e_{bc} - O_{bc}|$. The total deviation $d$ can be the sum of the deviations for each bucket-color combination:

$$ d =\sum_{b \in B}\sum_{c \in C_b} d_{bc}\;\; \text{where} \; d_{bc} = \left|\frac{N}{|C_b| }- O_{bc}\right|$$

The tricky part is determining the probability of different values of $d$ under our null hypothesis. I don't know if there is a nice mathematical formula, but you can get this computationally (to a high degree of accuracy) using simulation. The following pseudocode will help you approximate the null distribution of $d$.

```
d <- zero-vector with number_of_runs components
for r in 1...number_of_runs{   
  for p in 1....number_of_parts{         
    for b in 1...number_of_buckets{
       select a color from C_b (uniformly)
       assign that color to X_pb
    }
  }
  calculate discrepancy d_r
  d[r] <- d_r
}
```

Now that you have that, we can define the "homogeneity" of your actual sample as $1$ minus the p-value of the test of whether the color assignments were drawn uniformly (max heterogeneity). If we let $\hat{d}$ be the observed total discrepancy of our sample:

$$\text{Homogeneity} = 1 - P_{H_0}(d > \hat{d}) = P_{H_0}(d \leq \hat{d})$$

This has the property of being between $\eta$ and $1$, where $\eta = P_{H_0}(d = d_{\text{min}})$ with $\eta$ indicating maximum heterogeneity and $1$ being max homogeneity. Of course, you can translate by $\eta$ and scale by $1-\eta$ to get it back to a normalized scale of $0$ to $1$, but the un-scaled version will allow one to measure the absolute heterogeneity of samples [in some sense]. Larger numbers of parts, buckets, and/or colors allow greater heterogeneity such that $\eta \to 0$ as the number of choices/parts increases.